# How to make search with condition using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to make search within specific condition using codeigniter framework 
when I press inside my view the condition doesn't happen
(`$this->db->where('del_status','1');`) 
I think my problem in query to data base.

**my data base model**

```
public function SearchData($tablename,$data)
{
    //select * from users where username like'%ss%' AND del_status ='1'

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from($tablename);
    $this->db->like('username', $data);
    $this->db->or_like('fullname', $data);
    $this->db->or_like('email', $data);
    $this->db->where('del_status','1');
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    return $sql->result();
}
```

**this is my controller**

```
public function Search()
    {
        if($this->input->post("action") =="searchonusers" )
        {
            $data=$this->input->post("data");
            $this->load->model("DatabaseModel");

            $serachdata=$this->DatabaseModel->SearchData("users",$data);
            if(is_array($serachdata)&&count($serachdata)>0)
            {
                echo '<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="userdataa table-responsive">
                <table class=" table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover ">
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>user name</th>
                        <th>full name</th>
                        <th> image</th>
                        <th>email</th>
                        <th>type</th>
                        <th>status</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>time</th>
                        <th>delete</th>
                        <th>edit</th>
                        <th>Activate</th>
                    </tr>';

                foreach ($serachdata as $user):
                    echo'<tr id="'."user".$user->id.'">
                        <td>'.$user->id.'</td>
                        <td>'.$user->username.'</td>
                        <td>'.$user->fullname.'</td>
                        <td><img  class="img-responsive" height="40%" width="40%" src="'.base_url()."upload/".$user->image.'"></td>
                        <td>'.$user->email.'</td>';
                    $usertype='';
                    if($user->type== '1'){
                        $usertype=" <label class='label label-warning'>User</label>";
                    }else{
                        $usertype="<label class='label label-danger '> Admin</label>";
                    }
                    echo '<td>'.$usertype.'</td>';

                    $acativate='';
                    $status='';
                    $regstatus=$user->status;
                    if($regstatus == '0'){
                        $acativate='<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs showsta" status="'.$user->status.'" id="'.$user->id.'">enable</button>';
                        $status='<label class="label label-danger">disactive</label>';

                    }else{
                        $acativate='<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger showsta" status="'.$user->status.'" id="'.$user->id.'">disable</button>';
                        $status='<label class=" label label-success">active</label>';
                    }

                    echo' <td>'.$status.'</td>

         <td>'.$user->date.'</td>
         <td>'.$user->time.'</td>
        <td><button class="deleteuserfirst btn btn-danger btn-xs"  id="'.$user->id.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>delete</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edituser" id="'.$user->id.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#usereditorwe"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</button>
        <td> '.$acativate.'</td>

                    </tr>';

                endforeach;


               echo'</table>
            </div>
        </div>';

            }else{
                echo '<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="userdataa table-responsive">
                <table class=" table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>user name</th>
                        <th>full name</th>
                        <th> image</th>
                        <th>email</th>
                        <th>type</th>
                        <th>status</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>time</th>
                        <th>delete</th>
                        <th>edit</th>
                        <th>Activate</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="12">No Data Found</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                </div>';
            }

        }else{
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

**this is my ajax code**

```
$(".serchdata").on("click",function () {

    var action="searchonusers";
    var data=$("#dataa").val();
    if(data ==""){
        alert("Please Insert Your Search Data ... ")
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url("Users/Search")?>",
            method: "post",
            data:{action:action,data:data},
            success:function (data) {
                $(".userdata").remove();
                $(".box").remove();
                $("#pagination_link").remove();
                $(".serchresult").html(data)
                Table();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `is_array` on an *object* type `result()` :

```
if(is_array($serachdata)&&count($serachdata)>0)
```

to check for an array, use `result_array()` instead :

```
return $sql->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your model with that

```
public function SearchData($tablename,$data)
        {
            //select * from users where username like'%ss%' AND del_status ='1'

            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from($tablename);
            $this->db->like('username', $data);
            $this->db->or_like('fullname', $data);
            $this->db->or_like('email', $data);
            $this->db->where('del_status','1');
            $sql = $this->db->get()->result_array();
            return $sql;
        }
```